# Why is email sent using Send-MgUserMail cmdlet not having the From and Body, and getting rejected?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am using Powershell Send-MgUserMail cmdlet to send email using app credentials. I have created a test app and given it MsGraph Mail.Send application permission. After script execution, in the sender's account I get a Non-Delivery-Report saying the mail was rejected because of spam suspicion. But the curious thing is, the message does not have the From and Body, which I am setting in the email body.
Script:

```
Import-Module Microsoft.Graph.Users.Actions
$ClientId = "myappid"
$TenantId = "tenant id of contoso.com"
$ClientSecret = "clientSecret"
$ClientSecretPass = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $ClientSecret -AsPlainText -Force
$ClientSecretCredential = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $ClientId, $ClientSecretPass
Connect-MgGraph -TenantId $TenantId -ClientSecretCredential $ClientSecretCredential -NoWelcome
$sender = "alex@contoso.com"
$recipient = "cg@groups.outlook.com"
$subject = "Test mail to cg from alex"
$body = "Come and join us at the biggest tech event!"
$type = "Text"
$save = "false"
$params = @{
Message         = @{
          Subject       = $subject
          Body          = @{
              ContentType = $type
              Content     = $body
          }
          ToRecipients  = @(
              @{
                  EmailAddress = @{
                      Address = $recipient
                  }
              }
          )
      }
      SaveToSentItems = $save
}

Send-MgUserMail -UserId $sender -BodyParameter $params -Verbose
```

NDR received:
[image]

I am doing the same way as it's mentioned in many articles, but no idea why it's not working. Would really appreciate it if someone could help me here.

Article:
[https://o365info.com/send-mgusermail/#:~:text=You%20can%20send%20email%20from,cmdlet%20in%20Microsoft%20Graph%20PowerShell](https://o365info.com/send-mgusermail/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20send%20email%20from,cmdlet%20in%20Microsoft%20Graph%20PowerShell).

EDIT: **I am getting the same NDR even if I send the email to allan@contoso.com from alex@contoso.com using the script above.**
But the mail is being delivered if I send it from user1@outlook.com to user2@outlook.com

Comment: That script work okay for me, how do you know your not getting a body as the mail never arrives at it destination and you don't store it in the sent Items Folder ?. The most common reason for the spam notification is if you using a Development tenant as they tend to get abused by bad actors from time to time.

Comment: @GlenScales There is no From n Body in the diagnostics section of the NDR (which it usually has)

Comment: @GlenScales Is the script working for you to send email to a consumer group (i.e groups.outlook.com domain)?

Comment: NDR's will differ depending on what point in Transport Pipleline they are generated it's normal not to have the body in them. If it the sending server that generated the NDR (which is your case) then you should have the full message attached to the NDR. The reason is pretty clear in the NDR that it's ip level of the sending server so it not even scanning the Mail content (eg from,to,body,subject). Different Antispam services work in different ways some will look at the Mail Headers and any bad IP in the headers (eg used for abuse so you local ISP for instance) can cause this type of error.

Comment: One example I've seen is people use anonymous VPN services as their IPAddress are often abused.